# Попарное объединение элементов списка

Tags: python

Мне необходимо написать программу Python, которая берет слово из пяти букв и производит всевозможные двухбуквенные строки, основанные на буквах слова. (то есть, например, из слова тапок производит комбинации: *та*, *тп*, *то*, *тк*, *ат*, *ап* и т.д.). Использовать **itertools permutations** *нельзя*.

Написала следующую программу:

```
word = list('flash')
pairs = []
for i in word:
  i += [i+1]
  if i not in pairs:
    pairs.append(i)

print(pairs)
```

Но выдаёт ошибку на строке  `i += [i+1]`.

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Или код изначально неправильно написан?

Comment: `i` - это буква, А `i+1` - что вы этим хотели получить?

Comment: если заглянуть в [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) -  там можно найти реализацию оптимизированного алгоритма на чистом Python ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужны только пары, то можно "в лоб":

```
word = "flash"
pairs = []
for i in range(len(word)):
    for letter in word[:i] + word[i+1:]:
        pairs.append(word[i] + letter)
print(pairs)
```

В первом цикле берётся одна буква из слова. Во втором - клеится с каждой буквой из оставшихся.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

просто как один из вариантов:

```
word = 'flash'
pairs = []

for i in range(len(word)):
    pairs.extend(map(lambda x,y: x+y, (w:=list(word)).pop(i)*4, w))

print(pairs)  

'''
['fl', 'fa', 'fs', 'fh', 'lf', 'la', 'ls', 'lh', 'af', 'al', 'as', 'ah', 
 'sf', 'sl', 'sa', 'sh', 'hf', 'hl', 'ha', 'hs']
'''
```

в цикле `pop` поочередно выдергивает букву из слова, после чего функция `map()` соединяет ее с оставшимися буквами и `extend` добавляет результат в список пар.

PS. `w:=list(word)` работает в python 3.8 и новее